# Getting changes in object with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to learn how to track changes in a div. I found a post that showed the following code:

```
(async() => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', text => console.log(text));
   await page.goto('https://www.time.ir', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
   await page.evaluate(() => {
     $('#digitalClock').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
       window.onCustomEvent(e.currentTarget.textContent.trim());
     });
   });
 })();
```

When running this it pulls the time from the webpage and every second console.logs the new time - exactly what I'm looking for. However I'm having issues with any other page for some reason. For example, the very similar code below gives me an error:
'node:1801) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $$ is not defined'

```
await page.exposeFunction('onCustomEvent', text => console.log(text));
await page.goto('https://www.clocktab.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  await page.evaluate(() => {
      $('#digit2').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
        window.onCustomEvent(e.currentTarget.textContent.trim());
      });
    });
```

I'm not sure the difference between them other than the page I navigate to, and the element that I'm looking at to find the changing value. Additionally, I did read somewhere that DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated now, so if there's a better way to get what I'm looking for that would be great!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the second website there is not jquery, and when you send the evaluation function, $ is not defined.

Replace with vanilla js:

```
document.querySelector('#digit2').addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
    window.onCustomEvent(e.currentTarget.textContent.trim());
})
```

Suggestion: when i debug with the puppeeter evaluation function i copy-paste this on my browser console in the page. For example:

[image]